# How can I plus objects in an array in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm trying to do a calorie counter. I have an array with many food items and another array with the values of each food item (just numbers in order as the food).

I have 3 Spinners too that shows and allows the user to choose a food in every spinner, and then there is a plain `textview` that will show the resulting sum of the all calories for each food we've selected.
The only thing I need to know is how can I increment this number.

This is the 2 arrays that I got:

```html
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">calorias</string>
    <array name="comida">
        <item>Seleccione</item>
        <item>tortilla</item>
        <item>patatas fritas</item>
        <item>arroz</item>
        <item>salmon</item>
        <item>pollo</item>
        <item>pasta</item>
        <item>ensalada</item>
        <item>atun</item>
        <item>salchichas</item>
        <item>espinacas</item>
    </array>

    <array name="calorias">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>500</item>
        <item>674</item>
        <item>1170</item>
        <item>508</item>
        <item>199</item>
        <item>270</item>
        <item>98</item>
        <item>234</item>
        <item>1670</item>
        <item>310</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: You mean taking "calorias" array and sum an arbitrary number to an item of the array?

Comment: Yes, thats the way I'm working, If I select an item from "comida" in a spinner, it will be asigned to a number of the array "calorias" (in order). The things is that I need to get the resulting sum of all the 3 spinners and show it on a textview

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you cannot modify Android xml resources dynamically. Something like this is better stored in a database. You can look at Android's [Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room) to be able to save those values and then modify them.